# Ozone layer: why shouldn’t there be holes at the poles?

Tags: environmental-chemistry, atmospheric-chemistry, ozone

Just read "[What property allows ozone to absorb uv light](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35734/what-property-allows-ozone-to-absorb-uv-light)" together with excellent answers.
The driver here, i.e. the source of both the short and long wave UV, is of course sunlight. This is notably absent for six months of the year at the poles, so can anyone explain why one would "not" expect holes in the layer there?

Also, is it true that there have never been measurements of the layer that did "not" reveal holes at the poles?

Comment: Apart from anything else the holes were big enough to affect non-polar areas and were expected to lead to significant increases in hard UV at ground level in inhabited places.

Comment: I sense this has been interpreted as a climate debate platform - not true. There is good reason to suppose there is a complex dynamic at work here, for example the layer thickens as one moves towards the arctic circle, then thins towards the equator. This is surely counter intuitive! I am curious to know if this dynamic has been modelled and if the CFC influence is still regarded as the dominant mechanism.